Difference between Renaissance and Baroque Lutes in Relation to BWV 999
Bach's "Little Prelude" in C Minor, BWV 999, frequently played on keyboard, was originally written for lute. I asked a lutenist to play the piece, and he said he couldn't, because he played a Renaissance lute and the piece required a Baroque lute. (He made a comment about open strings ...?)
What is the difference between the two lutes that makes BWV 999 playable on one but not the other?
The score can be found on IMSLP.
Here's a link to YouTube performance (on keyboard) with score:



And, for the curious, here's the piece performed on lute.




The change of renaissance lute to baroque lute is marked by a change of how these instruments were typically played. Renaissance lute was played mostly melodically with adding chords and countermelodies. Baroque lute shifted more to the baroque bass-harmony model, and lute playing turned more into playing a bass with chords or some melody on top.
This did is in fact also lead to a change in hand position. The position you see in the video (where the hand is aligned to the strings) is the typical renaissance position. Baroque lute rather developed towards the position common on modern guitar, where the hand is at an angle to the strings, and the thumb plucks the bass, while the fingers pluck harmonies or melody. And this bass piece is actually exactly that, a bass line plus some broken chords. You will see that the video you selected using Renaissance hand position is little bit harder for playing music like this, compared to say:



(the reason why David Tayler is playing like this is most likely simply because he is specialized in earlier music).
Now, to get back to the question: This change of playing also led to a development of additional bass strings. The renaissance lute had 6-8 string choirs. With baroque lutes that went up to 14 choirs. But this means that music composed to be played using such bass strings cannot be translated to an instrument without bass strings.

David Tayler's lute is also tuned differently from Evangelina Mascardi's.

Without asking your lutenist precisely why his instrument is unsuitable, it's only possible to speculate, as there are many variations in the lute over the centuries.
For much of its life, particularly in the early Renaissance, the lute had six courses, tuned G-C-F-A-D-G.  If this describes the unsuitable instrument then it is unsuitable because it lacks the required range -- the lowest note available is G2, whereas BWV 999 requires D2 (as well as E♭2 and F♯2).
Another difference is that in the German baroque, at least, another tuning arose, where the top six courses were tuned to A-D-F-A-D-F.  The video posted in Lazy's answer shows Evangelina Mascardi playing an instrument in such a tuning, whereas David Tayler is using the G-C-F-A-D-G tuning.  From the Wikipedia article:

However, by around 1670 the scheme known today as the "Baroque" or "D minor" tuning became the norm, at least in France and in northern and central Europe. In this case, the first six courses outline a d-minor triad, and an additional five to seven courses are tuned generally scalewise below them. Thus the 13-course lute played by composer Sylvius Leopold Weiss would have been tuned (A″A') (B″B') (C'C) (D'D) (E'E) (F'F) (G'G) (A'A') (DD) (FF) (AA) (d) (f), or with sharps or flats on the lower 7 courses appropriate to the key of the piece.

Wikipedia also has an image of a 1732 chart showing that the seventh and eighth courses, tuned to F and G, can be fretted to give F♯ and G♯.
Obviously some lutenists can play the piece in each tuning, but perhaps your interlocutor finds it to be more trouble than it's worth in the older tuning.  David Tayler has a left-hand position shift in the fifth measure (if I counted correctly) that Evangelina Mascardi lacks.  David Tayler plays the low F♯ on the fourth fret of the low D string; Angelina Mascardi has an open string for that pitch.
Both players use an open string for the low E♭ and low D.  I am not a string player, but it seems quite possible that one or both of the chords with E♭ in the bass are impossible or unreasonably difficult if the E♭ is to be played on the first fret of the low D string.  If this is true, then a 7-course lute would also be unsuitable for the piece.
In fact, after some additional analysis, I note that the second chord is an augmented sixth, where the B♭ is the highest string fretted on the third or fifth fret, depending on the tuning, the G is on the fifth fret of the D string, and the C sharp is on the fourth fret of the A string.  Doing all of that while also playing the low E♭ on the first fret of the low D string does indeed seem impossible.  Thus, it seems most likely that the lutenist's instrument has insufficient bass strings to provide an open low E♭.
An 8-course lute is commonly tuned D-F-G-C-F-A-D-G, in other words, with a low F and low D added below the standard 6-course tuning.  It seems that the fretted portion of David Tayler's archlute has been retuned for this piece; if I'm not mistaken, the seventh course is tuned to D instead of F, to provide the low D and the low F♯, and the eighth is tuned for the low E♭.  It's also possible that the lutenist has an 8-course instrument but hasn't thought of this tuning or doesn't want to subject his instrument to it.
Another possibility is that he may just have learned the piece in the D minor tuning, so even if he technically could play it in the older tuning just as David Tayler does, it would require practice and relearning, so practically speaking he can't, at least not on short notice.

"Obviously some lutenists can play the piece in each tuning, but perhaps your interlocutor finds it to be more trouble than it's worth in the older tuning." —I'm put in mind of the recent question about violin scordatura, and how sometimes you see insensitive modern players play a scordatura piece in modern tuning. Not only do they lose the intended sound (fewer open strings, different string tensions), but to pull it off they usually have to use anachronistic modern technique, shifting all over the place, and anybody inclined that way is probably using other modern aesthetics too. It might...

... be that "I can't do it on this lute" translates to "I can't do it on this lute without losing part of the character of the work or using technique that just don't go with it." (Not baroque, but I'm also thinking of how many concertmasters play the opening notes of Saint-Seans' Danse Macabre in standard tuning instead of tuning down the E string, and how much is lost thereby!)
